# How to check usb host support on android device programmatically?

Tags: android, usb, accessory, usb-otg

I know that it was supported starting Android 3.1, i mean "how to check hardware support"

Comment: Curious if there had been a resolution that you had discovered.  Didn't have much luck searching within the forums for it.  Had this thought for part of an SDK that would like to know, but probably wouldn't want an exclusion of the app on the store if it was lacking the capability.

Answer (score 2):

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_USB_HOST

```
   context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_USB_HOST);
```

Comment: Google knows nothing about `ANDROID_FEATURE_HARDWARE_USB_HOST `

Comment: Please add some explanation in your answer as how and why does it solve the problem.. As it is, it is useless to others

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and after some googling I found this:
  http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=549

In summary, your app needs to use the UsbManager system service and enumerate through attached USB devices.

```
mUsbManager = (UsbManager) mApplicationContext.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> devlist = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
Iterator<UsbDevice> deviter = devlist.values().iterator();
while (deviter.hasNext()) {
    UsbDevice d = deviter.next();
    if (mUsbManager.hasPermission(d)) {
        UsbInterface usbIf = mDevice.getInterface(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < usbIf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
            if (usbIf.getEndpoint(i).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if your device does not support usb host, you will have empty usb devices list. so it seems that your solution does not work

Comment: Ah...I misunderstood the question. So are you asking how to check USB Host support before any USB devices are plugged in?

Comment: Of coarse, it depends on android device hardware possibilities, but not on attached usb devices

Comment: Any ways to find if the device has USB Host support before any USB devices are plugged in?

Comment: Have you tried the answer above (querying for 'PackageManager.FEATURE_USB_HOST')?