# how to check otg support option is enabled or not

Tags: android, usb-otg, android-usb

Currently one of our app required to external device connectivity. 
So,
I want to know how to check OTG support option in settings is enabled or not programatically.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598957/how-to-check-usb-host-support-on-android-device-programmatically) question might explains whether OTG is supported but I'm looking for settings option specifically, **But** the api returns True even on OTG Non-supporting device!!.
So that I can proceed with checking otg enabled or not check.

I'm also looking for it's solution, Since when ignoring [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598957/how-to-check-usb-host-support-on-android-device-programmatically) , since we ignored to perform the check, the app crashed stating that it **could not found .SO file**. For a moment we'are end up showing message, "Please ensure that OTG support is enabled in settings".

Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if Android has full USB support or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934248/how-to-detect-if-android-has-full-usb-support-or-not)